# TextToSpeech(this, this); does not work

Tags: java, android, this, text-to-speech, main-activity

Thanks for seeing my question.
My problem is that `TextToSpeech(this, this);` does not work.

I have initiated it in my code like this.

```
private TextToSpeech txt2Speech;
```

then inside `onCreate()`

```
    txt2Speech = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
```

And the end of my code I have declared an `onInitListener()` like this:

```
public void onInit(int status) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Yet Android Studio shows an error on this line -

```
    txt2Speech = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
```

Saying that

> required type `onInitListener()` does not match the type of my `class` which is `MainActivity.java`

What Have I Done Wrong?
Pls Help me.
Thank you in Advance

Comment: Does your activity implement `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener`?

Comment: Oh! Sorry it's getting pretty late here.  I have shut down the computer

Comment: But I think u are correct. This has happened before and I think this is the solution. The problem was that it was long back and I didn't remember. Pls post this as an answer. Tomorrow after I have checked it I'll mark it right. And thank you again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your Activity implements `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener`, something like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener
```

from there you are free to override the `onInit` method

```
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
     // your code
}
```